# Integration testing Devise using Test::Unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, integration-testing

I've installed and integrated Devise into my app and now I'm building its testing suite.  I'm using the default testing suite (Test::Unit?) that comes with Rails 4.2.1 and am currently working on the integration suite.

**INTEGRATION TEST:**

```
  def setup
    @user = User.create(email: "user@hlist.com", 
                        encrypted_password: Devise.bcrypt(User, 'password1'))
    @post = { title: "This is the title",
               content: "Detailed comment."*10,
               phone: 9991118888,
               email: "email@hlist.com",
               user_id: users(:spiderman).id }
    @p = @user.posts.build(@post)
  end

  test "creates a new post successfully" do 
    sign_in_as(@user)
    get new_post_path(@user)
    assert_template 'posts/new'
    assert_difference 'Post.count', 1 do 
      post posts_path, post: @post
    end
    assert_template 'posts/show'
  end
```

I also created the following method in my **test_helper.rb** file:

```
  def sign_in_as(user)
     post_via_redirect user_session_path, 'user[:email]' => user.email, 
                           'user[:encrypted_password]' => Devise.bcrypt(User, 'password1')
  end
```

However, I get the following error when I run the test:

```
  1) Failure:
PostsCrudTest#test_creates_a_new_post_successfully [/Users/harishramachandran/dropbox/documents/harish/coding/workspace/h_list/test/integration/posts_crud_test.rb:19]:
expecting <"posts/new"> but rendering with <[]>
```

I looked for the solution online and all I've been able to find is solutions that involve RSpec or Capybara.  This is an app I'm creating to learn, among other things, the default suite before I move on to RSpec and Capybara in a different app.  Is there a way to resolve this issue in Test::Unit?

Comment: I don't think you should pass @user to the `get new_post_path(@user)` because the get new_post_path is just a form. When you create the post, the create action should take care of creating a post that is associated with the current user. Try `get new_post_path`

Comment: I just tried that and it's giving me the same eror.

Comment: Is it possible to use Unit::Test integration tests with devise?  Or should I just stick with controller & model tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you create your post in `post posts_path, post: @post` you are not being redirected to the the post/show. Type `follow_redirect!` right after like so:

`post posts_path, post: @post
follow_redirect!`

or alternatively you can do `post_via_redirect posts_path, post: @post` which will do the same. Post and then redirect to post/show.

**A few notes** Devise.bcrypt is deprecated as of a few days ago. So in the future if you update your Gemfile you will get an deprecation error.
Yes you can do integration tests with Rails default testing. This is an example testing if the user gets the root path with or with out signing in.

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserFlowsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "user can see home page after login" do
    get user_session_path
    assert_equal 200, status
    @david = User.create(email: "david@mail.com", password: Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, "helloworld"))
    post user_session_path, 'user[email]' => @david.email, 'user[password]' =>  @david.password
    follow_redirect!
    assert_equal 200, status
    assert_equal "/", path
  end

  test "user can not see home page without login" do
    get "/"
    assert_equal 302, status
    follow_redirect!
    assert_equal "/users/sign_in", path
    assert_equal 200, status
  end
end
```

Rails classes for testing (ActiveSupport::TestCase, ActionController::TestCase, ActionMailer::TestCase, ActionView::TestCase and ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest) inherit assertions from [minitest assertions](http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/Minitest/Assertions.html) not [test unit](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html). This is true for your Rails version.